# Linq expression to find the max value of a List<List<int>>?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a cool Linq expression to find the max int value in a `List<List<int>>`?

Currently doing:

```
int maxValue = 0;
foreach(List<int> valueRow in values)
{
    // linq expression to get max value
    int value = valueRow.OfType<int>().Max(); 
    if (value > maxValue)
    {
        maxValue = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [**`SelectMany()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) for this which flattens the nested list, then you can just take the maximum of the resulting sequence:

```
int maxValue  = values.SelectMany( x => x).Max();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. You can get the maximum of the maximum of each nested list, like this:

```
int maxValue = values.Max(row => row.Max());
```

On a side-note: your `OfType<int>` isn't necessary since the list was already a `List<int>`.

Comment: Both solutions would work.  Though I would think that searching for maximums for each row then maximum of the maximums would not be as efficient as searching for the maximum of the flattened list.

Comment: The difference would be negligable though, since you're still looping over the same number of elements, with basically just one extra comparison per nested list. Which syntax you prefer is going to make a bigger difference here. :)