# Return min/max number in nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find the min/max number within a nested list using Linq.

An example class would be:

```
public class ListA
{
    public HashSet<HashSet<int>> nestedList;

    public ListA()
    {
        nestedList = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>()
        {
            new HashSet<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7 },
            new HashSet<int> { 2, 12, 7, 19 },
            new HashSet<int> { 6, 9 , 3, 14 }
        };
    }

    public int MaxNumber
    {
        // return the highest number in list
    }
}
```

In the example above, the minimum number would be 1 and the max number 19.

I'm struggling to get anything to get valid syntax. Anyone help?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show your attempts.

Comment: Duplicate of [Linq expression to find the max value of a List<List<int>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381215/linq-expression-to-find-the-max-value-of-a-listlistint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nestedList.SelectMany(item => item).Max();
```

and

```
nestedList.SelectMany(item => item).Min();
```

Comment: How embarrassing - I was trying to use a second Select after SelectMany - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`SelectMany`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany) and `Max` will likely produce the result you desire.

*Also consider using `DefaultIfEmpty` (with whatever default makes sense for your context) - this will ensure that `Max` doesn't throw an exception if `nestedList` is empty.*

```
public int MaxNumber
{
    get { return nestedList.SelectMany(z => z).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max(); }
}
```