# LINQ Max() in the list inside the list

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling with LINQ query. I have to find the highest value (Max) of votes for candidate across all Constituencies (using list of Constituencies) and get the ConstituencyName, CandidateName and Votes value. It means I have to find the highest value inside two lists and select object Constituency (or at least get its value).

```
public class ListOfConstituencies()
{
    public List<Constituency> Constituencies {get;set;}
}

public class Constituency
{
    public string ConstituencyName {get;set;}
    public List<Candidate> Candidates {get;set;}
}

public class Candidate
{
    public string CandidateName {get;set;}
    public int Votes {get;set;}
}
```

I was trying many solutions but I couldn't find one which fits my problem like:
[Join two tables using LINQ Query and order based two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789659/join-two-tables-using-linq-query-and-order-based-two-parameters) or
[Linq expression to find the max value of a List<List<int>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381215/linq-expression-to-find-the-max-value-of-a-listlistint)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and sample output? Your description is a little unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a select many into a single enumerable of anonymous objects containing the constituency and candidate, then sort and grab the first.

```
var candidate = Contituencies
.SelectMany(constituency => constituency.Candidates.Select(candidate => 
   new 
   {
     Constituency = constituency, 
     Candidate = candidate
   }))
.OrderByDescending(candidateInfo => candidateInfo.Candidate.Votes).FirstOrDefault();
string constituencyName = candidate.Constituency.ConstituencyName;
string candidatename = candidate.Candidate.CandidateName;
int votes = candidate.Candidate.Votes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous combined with orderbydescending to solve this.

```
var contituencyWithMostVotes = Constituencies
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Contituency = c,
        Candidate = c.Candidates.OrderByDescending(can => can.Votes).First()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Candidate.Votes).First();
```

The result "contituencyWithMostVotes " is an anonymous object that has 2 properties.

1. The actual Constituency object
2. The candidate that had the most votes in that constituency.

You can retrieve all information from those properties.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as you end up with a list of objects of the following structure:
{
   Constituency Candidate;
   IEnumerable<int> Votes;
}

Comment: @Dan the query results in a single object due to the sort. As I noted then after that, the actual object is accessible along with the "Votes" it has.

Comment: Right its a single object, but its objects of the wrong types...  Read the class definition I put in my first comment and see, you are outputting a "Constituency" object named "Candidate" and a "IEnumerable<int>" object named "Votes".   I'm not even sure what OrderByDescending of an "IEnumerable" field will do.   The correct operation would be the one detailed in my answer.  A SelectMany query

Comment: Take another look at your object... what type is the Votes variable of your anonymous object...   If you were to change "c.Candidates.Select(can => can.Votes)" to "c.Candidates.Select(can => can.Votes).Max()" then it would work as you described....  But still wouldn't give the candidate as the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) to flatten and project the nested list of candidates to anonymous types and then use [MoreLinq's](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) `MaxBy()` feature to get the one with the most votes.

```
var result = constituencies.SelectMany(con => con.Candidates, (con, can) => 
new { Constituency = con, Candidate = can })
.MaxBy(x => x.Candidate.Votes);
```

Comment: I've read about it but unfortunately, I cannot use it in my solution (it's task in which I can use only System.Linq)